# Google AppEngine application 502 Server error

Tags: google-app-engine

I created a sample Spring Boot Java application to deploy on Google App Engine flexible environment.

I used `./gradlew jettyrun` to run locally and it works.

I was able to deploy to App Engine using `./gradlew appenginedeploy` successfully

However, I get an HTTP `502` error when I try to test the REST call.